# Euler-Fermat Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I am trying to teach myself number theory, and while trying to work on some exercises I got stuck trying to prove that, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, 
$$
n^{91} \equiv n^{7} \bmod 91
$$
What I first thought of was applying the theorem directly and then multiply by the number of n's that was necessary, getting something like
\begin{array}{ccc}
n^{72} &\equiv& 1 \bmod 91 \\
n^{91} &\equiv& n^{19} \bmod 91
\end{array}
Which is the same as finding 
\begin{array}{ccc}
n^{19} &\equiv& n^{7} \bmod 91 \\
n^{12} &\equiv& 1\ \bmod 91
\end{array}
But then I got stuck. Does anyone have anything that can give me a push? I am not looking for the answer, but more of a hint. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $91 = 13 \times 7$, so $a \equiv b \pmod {91}$ iff  $a \equiv b \pmod {13}$  and  $a \equiv b \pmod 7$. See [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Thanks!! One more question though. When doing the proof, the only way I could make it work is if , while using Fermat's little theorem to set the congruence `n^7 ≅ n (mod 7)`. Then I squared both sides to get `n^14 ≅ n^2 (mod 7)`. After that I divided by n to get `n^13 ≅ n (mod 7)`.Is this manipulation correct or did I just made my own math rules here?

Comment: @FSB For $n \neq 0$, $n^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, and for $n = 0$ it's trivial.

Comment: Right, so you would make that $n^{84} ≅ 1 (mod\ 7) $ and then multiply both sides by $ n^{7} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's test for $$n^{p\cdot q}-n^p\pmod {p\cdot q}$$ where $n$ is any integer and $p,q$ are prime

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^q\equiv a\pmod q$ for any integer $a$

$$n^{p\cdot q}-n^p=n^p\cdot\left((n^{q-1})^p-1^p\right)$$

$$ \text{ which is divisible by }n\cdot(n^{q-1}-1)=n^q-n \text{ which is divisible by } q$$

Again,

$$\text{if }p|n,p|(n^{p\cdot q}-n^p)$$

$$\text{else } (n,p)=1 \text{  and } n^p\equiv n\pmod p$$

$$\implies n^{p\cdot q}-n^p=(n^p)^q-(n^p)\equiv n^q-n\pmod p$$

$$p|(n^q-n)\iff p|(n^{q-1}-1)\text{ as }(n,p)=1$$

If we denote the order of $a\pmod p =\text{ord}_pa$ such that $(a,p)=1,$

as $p$ is prime, the highest value of $\text{ord}_pa$  will be $p-1$ and the other values of $\text{ord}_pa$ will divide $p-1$

Hence , we need $(p-1)$ to divide $(q-1)$ so that $p|(n^q-n)\implies p|(n^{p\cdot q}-n^p) $

Now, we know, $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $a\equiv b\pmod n$

$\implies a\equiv b\pmod {[m,n]}$ where $[m,n]=$lcm$(m,n)$

If $n^{p\cdot q}\equiv n\pmod q$ and $n^{p\cdot q}\equiv n\pmod p$

$\implies n^{p\cdot q}\equiv n\pmod {[p,q]}$

Now, $[p,q]=p\cdot q$ as $(p,q)=1$ as $p,q$ are distinct primes

Comment: So, if $q=13,q-1=12$ and as $(p-1)|12,p-1$ can be $1,2,3,4,6$ Among them the primes values of $p$ are $2,3,5,7$ If $p=7,p-1=6\implies q-1=6a$ where $a$ is any positive integer, so the prime values of $q$ can be $13,19,31,37,\cdots$